# Why does arrays stored to variable "name" in Chrome convert to strings?

Tags: javascript, arrays, google-chrome

When I run `var name = [1,2,3]` in Chrome's console and then access the value of `name` I get back `"1,2,3"`. Why is this the case?

[image]

Comment: It is not just `name`, also `status` does the same.... but only in the global scope... not in local scope inside functions

Answer (score 7, accepted):

What you are seeing is a global variable that is part of the `window` object. This is actually a value the browser uses that reflects the name of the window. (see [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/name))

Since `window.name` is a string getter/setter, your array is being cast to a string. (and the console operates in the "global scope", so `var name` and `window.name` are the same value. (if you were nested inside a function, this same behavior would not apply because it wouldn't be the global scope anymore)