# why declared variable has null and some variable has undefined value?

Tags: javascript, variables

[image]

can any one please explain why the value of name variable is "" . in java script declared variable always has value undefined?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31601839/why-does-arrays-stored-to-variable-name-in-chrome-convert-to-strings http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28029234/why-global-variable-name-changes-to-string Refer :)

Comment: @MithileshKumar - that doesn't answer this question at all?....